# GINA logon dialog not in focus/active

Tags: c++, gina

I have created a DLL to replace GINA.
When I call `WlxDialogBoxParam` to display my own logon dialog, the dialog does not get active. What am I doing wrong?
I have tried o call `SetActiveWindow` on the `WM_INITDIALOG` event, but that did not seem to help.

I call the `WlxDialogBoxParam` with the following parameters:

```
WlxDialogBoxParam(hWlx, GetMyInstance(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_LOGON), 0, DialogProc, (LPARAM)this);
```

where DialogProc is defined as follows:
Code:

```
INT_PTR DialogProc(UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
             SetFocus (GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDC_NAME));
             return FALSE;
        case WM_COMMAND: {
            switch (LOWORD(wp)) {
                case IDOK:
                    EndDialog(_hwnd, IDOK);
                    break;

         case IDCANCEL:
                    EndDialog(_hwnd, IDCANCEL);
                    break;
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```