# How to invoke a button using C++ Win32 API when press the enter button?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog, modal-dialog

i have created a dialogbox using c++ win32 API...
there are 3 text box,1 combo box and 3 buttons...

now i have 2 problems...

1.when i press the ENTER button,it invoke second button(ID_OK) function,but i want  to invoke first button(ID_MYBUTTON)...

2.i am using the code to focus a textbox is,

```
SetFocus(GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDC_NAME));
```

But it cant focus that dialogbox,i mean cursor position is there,but cant get any value,when i typed...

Can anyone resolve it?

Comment: About your 1st question, you can make your button the default ENTER target instead of the OK button.

Comment: that's only,i am asking,how to make it?

Comment: It's a property of the dialog container: You can set the 'AcceptButton' and 'CancelButton' properties to control the behavior for ENTER (Accept) or ESC (Cancel) key pressed.

Comment: thanks g-mak...i cant get you clearly...For your info,i am using c++ WIN32 API.not MFC.

Comment: Anonymous Coward's answer seems to point the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may answer both your questions:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/02/205624.aspx:

> Use the DM_SETDEFID message to set the default button in a dialog
>
> Use the WM_NEXTDLGCTL message instead of SetFocus()

```
// set default button
SendMessage(_hwnd, DM_SETDEFID, (WPARAM)ID_MYBUTTON, 0);
//TODO: if the former default button's style remains, update with BM_SETSTYLE

// set focus
SendMessage(_hwnd, WM_NEXTDLGCTL, (WPARAM)GetDlgItem(_hwnd, IDC_NAME), TRUE);
```

Comment: @Coward...thank u...set default button works fine...But cant focus that textbox...and also cant focus that dialogbox,bcz first i press the enter button,cant work anything,after i click the dialogbox only the default button function worked...so now i want **how to focus that dialogbox,then the textbox in dialogbox?**

Comment: What function do you use to create the dialog? DialogBoxIndirect()?

Comment: Using wlxDialogBoxParam() function...this problem occurs in logondialogbox while starting the system.

Comment: It is difficult to tell without seeing the code; it could be a problem within your DialogProc. Does the problem persist if you create a test project where you call DialogBoxParam() directly in WinMain?

Comment: i cant get u clearly Coward...But i am using `_pWinLogon->wlxDialogBoxParam(_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(_dialogResourceID), 0, _dialogProc, (LPARAM)this);                             _dialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);` these code only...

Comment: After some googling i found (1) someone with the very same problem [GINA logon dialog not in focus/active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609750/gina-logon-dialog-not-in-focus-active) and (2) a possible [solution](http://www.44342.com/security-f1225-t949-p1.htm) to the problem: **In your _dialogProc, case WM_INITDIALOG must return TRUE (not FALSE). And you may have to add SetForegroundWindow(hwnd).**

Comment: Thank u Coward,it works fine...just using SetForegroundWindow();not to specify return true or false...thanks a lot Coward...